# Replace highlighted selected text in Emacs by default

Tags: emacs

Contrary to many other text editors that I use when I select the text in Emacs and type over it, the text does not get replaced by. How can I change this behavior in Emacs?

Comment: I added the answer.I had to type the question to find the answer myself ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of removing the question I decided to answer it. The answer is explained in [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Replacing-highlighted-text.html).

```
(delete-selection-mode 1)
```